# Differential Amplifier, what is the purpose of extra emitter resistors?

Tags: transistors, differential

I am curious about this differential amplifier circuit:

[image]

What is the purpose of the two R'E resistors? I know that the big RE acts as to help set up the current source for the DC Q-points, but I have also seen this circuit without the resistors R'E.

Can someone please explain why you would want to add these two resistors?

Comment: In no particular order of importance: (1) It can greatly extend the range over which the diff-amp input differences manage to avoid saturating the BJTs; (2) It linearizes the current ratios between the collector currents and the current sink resistor, \$R_\text{E}\$; (3) It manages part variations for the case where the BJTs are discrete; (4) It manages operating temperature differences between BJTs; (5) It manages ambient temperature variations; and more I'm sure I've momentarily forgotten to add or else simply don't know about.

Comment: Those resistors are normally referred to as "emitter degeneration". In an opamp they can help improve the slew-rate capability of the amplifier.